# What time series statistical model can help me check lagged influences among different series?

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression, lags

When I was talking with a friend, he told me that it is possible to estimate the effect of some variable (a rise, for example) at time $t$ would impact another variable in time $t + n$ where n could be 2,3,4,5... by some $\beta$ parameter.

I am wondering if this type of relationship that is estimated by VAR (Vector auto-regression) can solve by analyzing the parameter estimations and forecasting; and through Impulse response analysis. Is that the case?

If not, what sort of models can estimate this lagged effect across different variables?

Comment: VAR is fine when there is more than one endogenous variable in the system. When there is only one endogenous variable (while the other are exogenous), regression with ARMA errors could work.

Comment: Jus to add a little context. I has talking to a friend that works in the Credit Industry, and he told me that, the effect of a raise in unemployment would be felt about three months later in terms of their default statistics. 

I was am wondering how one could estimate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VAR is applicable when there is more than one endogenous variable in the system. On the other hand, when only the dependent variable is endogenous while the regressors are exogenous, a parsimonious alternative would be regression with ARMA errors (due to the possibility to use MA terms extra to the AR terms).

In your application, default statistics can probably be treated as exogenous to unemployment (since they would not affect it). Therefore, a regression with ARMA errors should work fine.

Comment: Perhaps my ARMA theory is a bit off, but let me try and see if I understand. Is it "ok" to estimate my model such that, for example,
 $Y_t = \beta_1Y_{t-1} + \beta_2Y_{t-2}  + \beta_3X_{t-1} + \beta_4X_{t-2} + \theta(e_t-1)$, where $\theta$ is the MA function on the errors?

Comment: This seems a bit off in terms of in terms of the Auto-regression part :)

Comment: @GuilhermeMarthe, No. First, you forgot the contemporaneous error term $e_t$ in the equation (I suppose you meant $e_{t-1}$ instead of $e_t-1$). Second, this is an ARMAX model rather than regression with ARMA errors (see [this](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/)), but this is not really a problem.

Comment: You are very correct, I forgot the braces for the subscript in the error term. I found it a bit hard to express the correct ARMA model, and love the fact that you had a blog post precisely on my problem.

So, notation problems aside, to find the correct set lags ($q$) for the covariate $X_{t-q}$ would to be inserted in the ARMA model for $Y_t$ would be a regular time series estimation problem (Box-Jenkins and ACF + PACF examination) but looking at how lags of $X$ affect $Y$?

Comment: @GuilhermeMarthe, finding "correct" lags is one problem, estimating their influence is another. Just as in a VAR model, several lag orders should be examined and the most appropriate one selected among them. Then the estimated model (regression with ARMA errors) will contain the information on how lagged $x$ affects $y$.